# Send text to textarea in webbrowser

Tags: c#, browser, textarea

i have a webbrowser component in a windows application.

could anybody please tell me how to **send text to textboxes in webpages** appearing in this browser programatically?

my HTML code

```
<textarea name="message" id="vB_Editor_QR_textarea" rows="10" cols="60" style="width:100%; height:100px" tabindex="1" dir="ltr"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

Edit:
Edit: Can you post your code?? I tried and it worked.

1. I added a WebBrowser control and during Form Load I set the HTML

   `webBrowser1.DocumentText = "<textarea name='message' id='t' rows='10' cols='60' style='width:100%; height:100px' tabindex='1' dir='ltr'></textarea>";`
2. Added a button and added the following code for Button Click event

`HtmlElement el = webBrowser1.Document.All["t"];`

`el.InnerText = "Hello World";`

and it works.

WebBrowser has [Document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.document.aspx) property using which you can achieve your requirements. For example to click a button you can use the following code

```
HtmlElement el = webBrowser1.Document.All["btnI"];
if (el != null) el.InvokeMember("click");
```

[Sample code is copied from here](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/33025210/webbrowser-control--simulate-click.aspx)

[WebBrowser Class documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d61470az.aspx)

Hope this serves as a starting point. Try it and If you have any specific issues. Update your question and we will help.

Comment: Thank ur reply But i still dont know how to send text to textarea.Plz help me

Comment: like I said.. try out.. the code above shows how you can get the object of a button. Try out for the TextArea.. Please try something. Don't worry if it does not work. Post it here. I would like people to learn and not copy. :)

Comment: //browser.Document.GetElementById("vB_Editor_QR_textarea").SetAttribute("value", "Hello"); It don't work. Im a newbie C#

Comment: @Max .. i edited the post yesteday. did you try the code I posted.